# Rearranging arrays - java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to rearrange my Person array according to age from youngest to eldest using the code below.

```
public class Trial {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Person[] person = new Person[3];

        person[0] = new Person("Jerome", 21);
        person[1] = new Person("Jam", 16);
        person[2] = new Person("Imelda", 53);

        for(int i=0; i<person.length;i++){
            System.out.println(person[i].getName() + " " + person[i].getAge());
        }

        String name = "";
        int age = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i=1;i<person.length;i++){

            name = person[i].getName();
            age = person[i].getAge();

            counter = i - 1;

            while(i>-1&&person[counter].getAge()>age){
                person[counter+1].setAge(person[counter].getAge());
                person[counter+1].setName(person[counter].getName());
                counter -= 1;
            }


            person[counter+1].setAge(age);
            person[counter+1].setName(name);

        }

        for(int i=0; i<person.length;i++){
            System.out.println(person[i].getName() + " " + person[i].getAge());
        }

    }
}
```

The algorithm runs smoothly with arrays of integer but here, I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.example.java.Trial.main(Trial.java:28)
```

This is where the error points to

```
while(i>-1&&person[counter].getAge()>age){
                person[counter+1].setAge(person[counter].getAge());
                person[counter+1].setName(person[counter].getName());
                counter -= 1;
            }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another way of arranging object arrays according to a specific variable?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. If you implement that, you can use Java's [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: The problem is that you interleave two index variables. But nevertheless, this is not how someone is supposed to sort objects.

Comment: check the `counter`value in your loop, not `i`value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make `Person` implement `Comparable`, you can use `Arrays.sort(...)` to do this for you!

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    // Existing class implementation

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return p2.age - this.age;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can implement your `compareTo` method directly inline when `Arrays.sort()` is called (ie: no modification to `Person` is required):

```
Arrays.sort(personArray, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p2.age - p1.age;
    }
});
```

If you're running Java 8, this can be shortened even further using a lambda expression:

```
Arrays.sort(personArray, (p1, p2) -> p2.age - p1.age);
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I'll definitely try this because most of you tell that the code above is not a good way of sorting objects in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
     for(int i=1;i<person.length;i++){
```

To

```
     for(int i=1;i<=person.length;i++){
```

Comment: the value of counter is always gets updated irrespective of the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The *core* problem is indeed located there:

```
while(i>-1&&person[counter].getAge()>age){
    person[counter+1].setAge(person[counter].getAge());
    person[counter+1].setName(person[counter].getName());
    counter -= 1;
}
```

In the `while` loop, you do a *bounds-check* on `i` (`i > -1`), but you use `counter` instead. So in order to solve the core problem, you have use `counter` instead of `i`:

```
while(counter>-1&&person[counter].getAge()>age){
    person[counter+1].setAge(person[counter].getAge());
    person[counter+1].setName(person[counter].getName());
    counter -= 1;
}
```

Nevertheless, that's not a good way to sort objects in an array. Because of several reasons:

- Instead of swapping *objects*, you exchange the *state* of these objects. Imagine that later in the project, you have to add a new field to `Person`, then your algorithm is ruined. Furthermore it is possible that there are other references to that `Person` that will see its `name` and `age` change.
- You are implementing an *insertion sort* algorithm whereas [*QuickSort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [*MergeSort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) outperform [*insertion sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) significantly.

## Problem with exchanging state

If you exchange the state of your objects, that's something different than exchanging their position in the array. Imagine that you wish to extend your program: now people can be married. It means for instance you hold an array somewhere of a `Person` that is married tot Bob. Say Bob is married to Alice. If later you modify the name of Bob to Cindy, all of a sudden Cindy is married to Alice.

You can solve that problem, by rewriting your code to:

```
for(int i=1;i<person.length;i++) {
    Person toSwap = person[i];
    counter = i - 1;
    while(counter >-1 &&person[counter].getAge()>age) {
        person[counter+1] = person[counter];
        counter -= 1;
    }
    Person[counter+1] = toSwap;
}
```

Furthermore it is advicable to turn a `while` in a `for`, because there is less chance of producing an infinite loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<person.length;i++) {
    Person toSwap = person[i];
    for(counter = i-1; counter >-1 &&person[counter].getAge()>age; counter--) {
        person[counter+1] = person[counter];
    }
    Person[counter+1] = toSwap;
}
```

## Sorting algorithms

You basically implement a version of [*insertion sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). Insertion sort takes an object, looks for all larger (or smaller) objects, shifts these objects one to the right (left) and then positions the object on the correct position. This runs worst case in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* or *quadratic time*. It means that in the worst case if you double the length of your list, it will take four times more time to solve the problem.

Computer scientists have come up with better ways to sort like [*QuickSort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [*MergeSort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). *MergeSort* for instance runs in *O(n log n)*. This means that if you double the length of your list, the time it takes to sort doubles as well and there is one time unit added. What that time unit is (one millisecond, nanosecond, 78 seconds,...) is unknown, but eventually, if the list is large enough, *MergeSort* will outperform *InsertionSort* for an unsorted list.

## Using builtins

Java offers a large amount of classes, methods and algorithms. By using these algorithms, you use a lot of research in how things should be done error-safe, efficient and without much/any side-effects.

In order to do an *error-safe* and *fast* sorting, you can use [`Arrays.sort(T[],IComparator<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thanks, man! By the way, I'm new to java and this was the only solution I could think of.

Comment: May I know why the algorithm above is not a good way of sorting objects in an array?

Comment: @amazingsaluyot: don't take the comments as insulting. I've only wanted to show why using `.set` methods on person is not a good idea.

Comment: @amazingsaluyot: well the answer addresses two problems: first you use `.set` instead of performing a reference swap: this means that you *modify* the state of the `Person`. Alice is all of a sudden renamed to Bob and Bob is renamed to Alice. Now imagine Bob is also married to Cindy, then after your sorting, Cindy will be married with Alice.

Comment: That made sense! I didn't take your comments as insulting. I've recently started reading _Introduction to Algorithms_ by _Thomas Cormen_ and that's where I've read about insertion sort and got the idea of using it to my code. As I've said, I'm new to programming and I'm open for corrections and suggestions. Cheers!